# 220v hot glue gun with Great Britain plug to be used in USA

Tags: voltage

I was mistakenly sent a 220v hot glue gun with a Great Britain plug . The plug also has a 5 amp fuse within it. Can this be used in the USA with just an adapter, or does it also need a converter/transformer?

Comment: Transformer would cost more than a glue gun

Comment: Are some appliances 220v in USA? If so change the UK plug and use that 220v socket...

Comment: @SolarMike - high power electric appliances like clothes dryers and stoves typically are. You would only find special 220V outlets near those appliances, though. And they are really bulky!

Answer (score 4):

You could just try and see if it works (gets hot enough) at 110 V.

The teardown of a gluegun by [BigClive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obMjAoMoESE) reveals that the heating element is a [PTC thermistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor) which means it regulates its own power to maintain a certain temperature.

At 110 V the maximum power (when the PTC is cold) will be lower (compared to when used at 220 V) but after heating up the power required is lower anyway.

So I would just try and see if it works and if not, buy a new glue gun, they're cheap.

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning on using it on a 110V outlet you'll need a 110V/220V transformer, otherwise it won't get hot enough to melt the plastic.

Comment: Glue guns are $10 Maybe just buy another one? Would be cheaper than a transformer.

Comment: Unless he already has a transformer he can use, I totally agree with you.